# Qt primitive types, racing with QTimer, and C++

Tags: c++, qt, race-condition, primitive-types

I'm walking in some trouble with this particular piece of code. It has either a race condition or a problem with quint8.

```
quint8 chunk3[CHUNK_SIZE_MULT];
memset(chunk3,0x00, sizeof(chunk3));
for (int cx = 0; cx < CHUNK_SIZE; cx++)
    for (int cz = 0; cz < CHUNK_SIZE; cz++) {
        int i = cx * CHUNK_SIZE + cz;
        float abs[2];
        abs[0] = x * CHUNK_SIZE + lastPosX + cx;
        abs[1] = z * CHUNK_SIZE + lastPosZ + cz;
        int perlin = (int)(wallsPerlin->Get(abs[0], abs[1])) % 8;
        chunk3[i] = perlin > 6 ? perlin : 0;//(int)(sin(i) + 1.0 * 32.0);
    }
```

if I use chunk3[i] = 0 or 30 or i % 30, it will work fine. However when I introduce a sin function, rand function or perlin noise, it will throw throw memory faults. I thought it might have been the conversion from double to char, but this now seems unlikely.

Can someone clarify whether this is related to quint8 or timing?

Is use a QTimer interval to call the above code and OpenGL related functions, would it be possible that the QTimer fires an event without finishing the previous one?

If so, how could I construct my gameloop better with Qt? Using usleep?

EDIT: I see now that is not a timing issue, since leaving perlin and printing it, but setting chunk3[i] to a fixed 30 works fine.

EDIT: casting int to quint8 does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: one thing that pops right up is that quint8 is one byte of data, and you're inserting (int) cast values into it (4 bytes). I don't think it's your problem, but I'd fix that :). also, is CHUNK_SIZE_MULT exactly CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE?

Comment: I'm casting to an int first, because I thought it might've been the problem that it was casting a double to a char. But I think that's not the problem. CHUNK_SIZE_MULT is indeed CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE.

Comment: I see now that is not a timing issue, since leaving perlin and printing it, but setting chunk3[i] to a fixed 30 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        quint8 perlin = (quint8)((int)(wallsPerlin->Get(abs[0], abs[1])) % 8 + 8);
```

Fixed it.